# Differential as bundle map and pull back bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

In the wikipedia article about the [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)), it is stated that if $f: M\to N$ is smooth, then it induces a bundle map $df: TM \to TN$. It is then claimed that equivalently $f_*=df$ is a bundle map from $TM$ to the pullback bundle $f^* TN$.

Why is this equivalent? The bundles $TN$ and $f^* TN$ are clearly not the same as they are bundles over different spaces. They could be isomorphic, but is still seems strange that this would hold independently of $f$.

Edit: The full quote is

> Equivalently (see bundle map), φ∗ = dφ is a bundle map from TM to the pullback bundle φ∗TN over M, which may in turn be viewed as a section of the vector bundle Hom(TM, φ∗TN) over M. The bundle map dφ is also denoted by Tφ and called the tangent map. In this way, T is a functor.

Comment: $TM$ and $f^*TN$ are both bundles over $M$, not bundles over different spaces.

Comment: @user10354138 You are right. But whis was only a typo. As can be seen from the context of the question, I am interested in $TN$ and $f^*TN$.  I corrected the question accordingly

Comment: Please, provide a complete quote, afik, the wikipedia article contains no such claim. (It says, however, correctly, that "Then, applying the differential pointwise to $X$ yields the pushforward $\phi_*X$, which is a vector field along $\phi$, i.e., a section of $\phi^*TN$ over $M$." The word "yields" is not the same as "is".

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I added the quote

Comment: OK, then it is just sloppyness in the article; keep in mind that different parts could have been written by different people. The correct statement is "Then, applying the differential pointwise ..."

Comment: @MoisheKohan I dont get what you mean with pointwise. I was under the impression that $df: TM \to T N$ is a bundle map.  But where does the pull-back bundle come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the definition of the pull-back bundle (in the context you are interested in): If $f: M\to N$ is a smooth map, $df: TM\to TN$ is the differential of $f$, then (as a topological space) 
$$
f^*(TN)=\{(x,\xi): x\in M, \xi\in TN, \xi\in T_{f(x)}N\}\subset M\times TN. 
$$
The bundle structure on $f^*(TN)$ is given by the projection 
$$
\pi: (x,\xi)\mapsto x. 
$$
Now, $df$ defines a bundle map $TM\to f^*(TN)$ which I will denote $Df$:
$$
Df: (x,\eta)\mapsto (x, df_x(\eta)), x\in M, \eta\in T_xM.
$$
I will leave it to you to check that $Df$ is indeed a morphism of vector bundles 
$$
Df: TM\to f^*(TN). 
$$
By abuse of notation, one frequently denotes the morphism $Df$ simply $df$ since the"interesting" parts of these morphisms are the same.

Given a vector field $X\in {\mathfrak X}(M)$, the push-forward $f_*(X)$ is the section $Y$ of $f^*(TN)$ which is given by the formula
$$
Y_x= Df(X_x). 
$$
That's all what there is to it. The wikipedia article commits a minor and common abuse of notation by using the notation $df$ for $Df$.

Comment: Thank you, this written very clearly. Just one last thing: If $f$ is a submersion, does this mean $TN \simeq f^* TM$?

Comment: @Michael: No, it does not: Ranks could be different. What you need is a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: Really? What about if $f: X\times Y\to X$ is a projection?

Comment: Yes, really. As I said, you need the equality of ranks of $TN$ and $f^*TM$: It is clearly a necessary condition for isomorphism of these bundles. Note that the bundles $f^*TM$ and $TM$ have equal rank. But rank of the tangent bundle equals the dimension of the manifold. Hence, you are asking for $dim(M)=dim(N)$. But if you have a submersion between manifolds of equal dimension, it has to be a local diffeomorphism.