# Is Lie bracket of pull back tangent bundle well defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, lie-derivative

Given a smooth map $f: M\rightarrow N$ between smooth manifolds, by definition ([wiki reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258713/differential-as-bundle-map-and-pull-back-bundle)) we have a pull back tangent bundle $f^{*}TN\subset M\times TN$.

> Can we define a Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ for $X,Y\in  f^{*}TN$?

(It should because I have seen some property like $f_{*}([X,Y])=[f_{*}X,f_{*}Y]$ where $X,Y\in TM$. (ref: [Answers in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754877/f-related-vector-field)))

But there's a problem, in convention $[X,Y]=XY-YX$, but what does $X(Y)-Y(X)$ mean exactly for $X, Y\in f^{*}TN$?  For $p\in M$, given $h\in C^{\infty}{(V)}$, where $f(p)\in V$ open in $N$, it seems we should have $[X,Y]|_{p} h =X_p({Y(h)})-Y_p({X(h)})$. But $X_p\in T_{f(p)}N$, therefore $Y(h)$ should be in $C^{\infty}(V)$, but how could it be defined?

Comment: What does the juxtaposition $XY$ mean in this situation? Sections of $f^*(TN)$ are not derivations.

Comment: I have no idea, so $[f_{*}X, f_{*}Y]$ doesn’t make sense?

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$, and $f_*$ in that expression? The differential $f_*$ maps $TM$ to $TN$; it doesn't act in an obvious way on $f^*(TN)$.

Comment: I've added some reference, I'm just reading some notes without detail explanation, so sorry I'm not exactly sure. Is there a possible explanation, possibly with abuse of notations, that make $[f_{*}X, f_{*}Y]$ make sense?